# Extract table from NCBI page (JS) using Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hello I need to extract Feature table from protein page in NCBI webpage. Example of page is here:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/Q8TB36.3

I am writing script in Python 3.x, using BeautifulSoup package for getting html of page. Problem is, that if I download html source of this page, I am not getting Feature table - Feature table is generated by javascript?
Is there any way, how to call that script and generate Feature table on my own? Or any other way how to extract desired data from page?

Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript fetch data from this url:

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=269849682&db=protein&report=genpept&extrafeat=984&fmt_mask=0&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxplex=3&maxdownloadsize=1000000
```

You can make requests to this url and get the data you need.

You can find this url in Chrome Dev tools.